# how to sum jsonb values in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with postgres and I need to sum the value of jsonb fields

```
     Column      │         Type         │                             Modifiers
─────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 id              │ integer              │ not null default
 practice_id     │ character varying(6) │ not null
 date            │ date                 │ not null
 pct_id          │ character varying(3) │
 astro_pu_items  │ double precision     │ not null
 astro_pu_cost   │ double precision     │ not null
 total           │ jsonb                │
```

So I need to sum all the values for the total field for all the records and after that I need to use aggregate functions on them like min, max and avg

I started a query like this

```
select id, json_object_agg(key, val)
from (
    select id, key, sum(value::numeric) val
    from mytable t, jsonb_each_text(total)
    group by id, key
    ) s
group by id;
```

I'm confused after this. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

I need to use the aggregate function after adding all the values inside jsonb. Is that possible?

```
I'm getting a result like this


id   json_object_agg
25  { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }
26  { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }
24  { "b" : 2, "a" : 1 }
```

I was expecting this

```
 id   json_object_agg
   25    3
   26    3
```

Something like this

Comment: What you have looks pretty good, what is your problem with that query?

Comment: A better way to solve the problem would be to get rid of the JSON column and store your data in a properly normalized way.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you mean I should store integer instead of jsonb?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I need to use the aggregate function on this.

Comment: There are two aggregate functions in your query. What is missing?

Comment: First I need to sum the values. Then I have to use min over the sum values

Comment: Also I'm getting a result like this
`id.     json_obj_agg
25 { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }
26 { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }
24 { "b" : 2, "a" : 1 }`

Comment: I'll add this above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum all the values of the `total` column for each of the rows, you need to group by `id` but not by `key` :

```
select t.id, sum(tt.value::numeric) val
from mytable t, jsonb_each(total) AS tt
where jsonb_typeof(tt.value) = 'number'  -- to avoid errors in the sum() if non numeric values
group by t.id
```

To calculate the min, max, avg on all the rows of the table, you don't need to group the rows :

```
select min(s.val), max(s.val), avg(s.val)
from
(
    select t.id, sum(tt.value::numeric) val
    from mytable t, jsonb_each(total) AS tt
    where jsonb_typeof(tt.value) = 'number'  -- to avoid errors in the sum() if non numeric values
    group by t.id
) as s
```

Comment: It's giving me an error

Comment: ERROR:  cannot cast type jsonb to numeric
LINE 4:     select t.id, sum(tt.value::numeric) val

Comment: is this because of postgres version? I'm using a old one

Comment: What is your postgres version ? Postgres should be able to cast a jsonb value into numeric when the value is of jsonb type 'number'. You can try to first cast into text by replacing `jsonb_each` by `jsonb_each_text`.

Comment: Yeah jsonb_each_test is working fine. Thanks :)

Comment: hi. I have one more question. I'm not able to use jsonb_typeof(tt). I'm using postgres 9.6. But I checked I can use this. But still is there any alternative?

Comment: jsonb_typeof() already exists in postgres 9.6 so where is the issue ? Then if you are sure that all the values in the jsonb objects of your total column are of type numeric, then you can remove the where clause.

Comment: Still I'm getting this ERROR:  function jsonb_typeof(text) does not exist. It can be float value also

Comment: If you replace `jsonb_each(total) AS tt` by `jsonb_each_text(total) AS tt` in the `FROM` clause,  then you cannot use `jsonb_typeof(tt.value)` in the `WHERE` clause anymore because tt.value is of type text instead of jsonb. Either you remove the WHERE clause because you are sure that all the values of the jsonb objects in your `total` column are numeric values, or you have to convert `tt.value` into jsonb in the WHERE clause : `where jsonb_typeof(to_jsonb(tt.value)) = 'number'`

Comment: Okay. But why jsonb_each(total) is not working in this case. If it's there in postgres 9.6. It should work, right?

Comment: I can't tell you why you have this error in postgres 9.6, maybe the jsonb->numeric conversion is not implement yet in that version. however, if you want to keep the `jsonb_each(total) AS tt` in the `FROM` clause, then you can just add the text conversion in the `SELECT` clause : `select t.id, sum(tt.value :: text :: numeric) val`